# Ruby On Rails : create nested Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, hashmap

I'm trying to make an array of objects, let's call it "categories", and I want each object in this array to have an array called "items" within it, so the result will be something like this:

```
[category:id=11, name="beer", items[1,2,3,4]]
```

I've tried this code:

```
@category ||= Array.new
@categoryItems ||= Array.new
@venues.categories.enabled.each do |category|
  @category.push(category)
  @categoryItems.push(category.items.enabled)
end
```

but I don't know how to name the items inside so I can use them in json afterward. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try create hash.

```
@category ||= Array.new
@venues.categories.enabled.each do |category|
  hash = {}
  hash[:category][:id] = category.id
  hash[:category][:name] = category.name
  hash[:category][:items] = category.items.enabled.pluck(:id).join(',')
  @category << hash
end
```

Comment: ok this seems legit.. but i have  alittle problem concerning that.. it gives me error now that (undefined method enabled) for the last line .. it may or may not related to this issue..

Comment: Maybe in model Item You haven't scope **enabled**?